# Pygame character idle animation

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a 2D platform game using the Python module Pygame. I have made the background, the character and the movement for said player. You can move using a & d on the keyboard and jump with SPACE. However I cannot figure out how to make an idle animation for the player. I have the running animation, but I haven't made the sprites yet, so I just used the idle picture set.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, time, itertools

pygame.init()

# background image
walkRight = pygame.image.load('idle1.png')
walkLeft = pygame.image.load('idle1.png')
bg = pygame.image.load("background.png")
idle = [pygame.image.load('idle1.png'), pygame.image.load('idle2.png'), pygame.image.load('idle3.png')]
standcount = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# jump
isJump = False
jumpcount = 10

# window
display_width = 1000
display_height = 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

# title & icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Grand Theft Ewok")
icon = pygame.image.load('bear.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# player creds
x = 50
y = 430
vel = 10

# playerIMG
playerIMG = pygame.image.load('player.png')


def player(x, y):
    global standcount
    global walkcount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    # win.blit(playerIMG, (x,y))

    if walkcount + 1 >= 9:
        walkcount = 0

    if standcount + 1 >= 9:
        standcount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(idle[walkcount // 3], (x, y))
        walkcount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(idle[walkcount // 3], (x, y))
        walkcount += 1
    elif standcount:
        p = 0
        for frame in idle:
            win.blit(idle[p], (x, y))
            p += 1
            if p >= 2:
                p = 0
                continue

    pygame.display.update()


# game loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # movement
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > (vel - 25):
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 835:
        x += vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkcount = 0
        standcount = True

    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            left = False
            right = False

    else:
        if jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpcount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpcount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpcount = 10

    player(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

under the player function you can see where I tried to use a for loop, but it just doesn't work.

I am using Python 3.8.

Best wishes to all.

Stay indoors, Thanks.

**EDIT**
I have found out how to make the idle animation using this:

```
    elif standcount:
        p = 0
        for frame in idle:
            win.blit(idle[standcount], (x, y))

            standcount += 1

            #pygame.display.update()

            if standcount >= 2:
                standcount = 0
                continue
            pygame.display.update()
```

However, it iterates through the list extremely fast. I cant think of a way to slow it down without using time.sleep because then it will freeze the game every time I stop moving.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a loop, just do the same thing you did for the walking:

```
if left:
    win.blit(idle[walkcount // 3], (x, y))
    walkcount += 1
elif right:
    win.blit(idle[walkcount // 3], (x, y))
    walkcount += 1
else:
    win.blit(idle[standcount // 3], (x, y))
    standcount += 1
```

using a loop means it will blit all the images on top of each other in the same frame meaning you will only see the top/ last one. What you did for the walking animations works perfectly.

---

also, you should only have one `pygame.display.update()`. You should only update the screen at the end of each frame, not many times in a frame. Since you call `player()` right before updating the screen, you can get rid of one of them, as one will do nothing

---

So i found the problem, you had a `standcount = True` which would reset it to 1, getting rid of this solved the problem

Here is the full code edited:

```
import pygame, time, itertools

pygame.init()

# background image
walkRight = pygame.image.load('idle1.png')
walkLeft = pygame.image.load('idle1.png')
bg = pygame.image.load("background.png")
idle = [pygame.image.load('idle1.png'), pygame.image.load('idle2.png'), pygame.image.load('idle3.png')]
standcount = 0 # change it to an int, not a bool

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# jump
isJump = False
jumpcount = 10

# window
display_width = 1000
display_height = 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

# title & icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Grand Theft Ewok")
icon = pygame.image.load('bear.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# player creds
x = 50
y = 430
vel = 10

# playerIMG
playerIMG = pygame.image.load('player.png')


def player(x, y):
    global standcount
    global walkcount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    # win.blit(playerIMG, (x,y))

    if walkcount + 1 >= 9:
        walkcount = 0

    if standcount + 1 >= 9:
        standcount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(idle[walkcount // 3], (x, y))
        walkcount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(idle[walkcount // 3], (x, y))
        walkcount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(idle[standcount // 3], (x, y))
        standcount += 1        

    pygame.display.update()


# game loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # movement
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > (vel - 25):
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 835:
        x += vel
        right = True
        left = False
        #you could put standcount = 0 here to reset animation after walking
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkcount = 0
        #got rid of standcount = True
    if not (isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            left = False
            right = False

    else:
        if jumpcount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpcount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpcount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpcount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpcount = 10

    player(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

---

As for speed:

There are 2 options,

A) wait a certain amount time (i recommend)

B) wait a certain amount of frames (don't recommend)

Its best to do time as then performance doesn't affect the speed

So you already have time imported you can do this:

```
idle_frame_start = time.time() # get the current time - very accurate
walk_frame_start = time.time()

def player(x, y):
    global standcount, idle_frame_start
    global walkcount, walk_frame_start
    # win.blit(playerIMG, (x,y))

    if walkcount + 1 >= 4: #if the count is more than amount of images
        walkcount = 0

    if standcount + 1 >= 4:
        standcount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(idle[walkcount], (x, y))
        if time.time() - walk_frame_start > 0.8:
            walkcount += 1
            walk_frame_start = time.time()
    elif right:
        win.blit(idle[walkcount], (x, y))
        if time.time() - walk_frame_start > 0.8:
            walkcount += 1
            walk_frame_start = time.time()
    else:
        win.blit(idle[standcount], (x, y))
        if time.time() - idle_frame_start > 0.8: # if the time difference is bigger than 0.8s
            standcount += 1        
            idle_frame_start = time.time() # reset the start time

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it still isn't playing the animation for me.

Comment: @HomeMadeMusic Try changing `standcount = True` to `standcount = 0` at the top of your script

Comment: Again thanks, but it still isn't doing the animation what so ever.

Comment: Yeah that worked thank you. Do you think theirs a way to slow it down though, It moves at a moderately fast pace. It's meant to look like the character is breathing, so each picture should have roughly a 0.8 second delay.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you kindly Sir,

That fixed the problem perfectly, have a good time, stay safe!